# Fillable PDF forms in LibreOffice

Tags: javascript, pdf, libreoffice, fdf

As the title says I'm trying to create a fillable form inside of a PDF file using LibreOffice. Creating the form itself is not an issue, but is there some way to add scripts to forms? Adobe reader DC pro allows the use of javascript. Is there a way to use javascript in libreoffice forms too?

Thanks,
G3

Comment: Essentially, yes, because OpenOffice / LibreOffice creates a standard Acroforms PDF. I am not sufficiently familiar with LibreOffice, to see how the scripts can be added. But if everything fails, add the scripts in Acrobat. In any case, if you want to start scripting, get the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, downloadable from the Adobe website.

Comment: Well, the problem is is that I'm on linux and no pdf editor does the calculations added with acrobat :(